# disable anonymous access to embedded Spring Boot LDAP server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-ldap

Which properties I should configure to disable access to the embedded Spring Boot LDAP server via external LDAP browsers ?

Currently I have the following settings in my application.setting file

```
spring.ldap.embedded.credential.username=uid=admin
spring.ldap.embedded.credential.password=secret
```

I expected, that such settings will disable anonymous access, but it is not true -- I am able to modify the LDAP tree entries in the LDAP browser anonymously connected.